# Using a variable in a JSONPATH formula

Tags: soapui, jsonpath

I am using an excel spreadsheet as source for a SOAPUI test case. I need to retrieve an ID in a step and use it in another step.

So basically I would like in the first step to retrieve my ID, that is not a problem I do:
body.success[0]._key.rootId    =    $rootId

but when I try to use it in my second formula, it doesn't seem to want to interpret my variable:
body.request.quote.coverages[?(@.rootId == $rootId)][0]._type

Is there a way to do this ?